# On change select option change input filed value using Angular Js

Tags: html, angularjs

I have an input form. I have select option in the form. If option can be changed than input filed that have read-only property can changed according to the select option and after submit both post values.
select options like :-

```
<select ng-model="account" name="account" required="">
<option value="">Please Select</option>
<option  value="8.00">option 1</option>
<option value="7.00">option2</option>
<option value="10.00">option3</option>
</select>
```

I want values in

```
<input type="text"ng-model="pbonus" name="pbonus" readonly>
```

On change select option pbonus also can be chagend. if option1 is selected than pbonus should post value " 8.00 "  . if option2 is selected than pbonus should post value " 7.00 ".

Comment: Did you try setting the ng-model of pbonus to be "account"?

Comment: I have tried it but it do not post the value . I have add like this 
<input type="text" class="bonus" ng-model="account" name="pbonus" readonly> but it don't post values.

Comment: @Ranjeetsingh, try this: `<input type="text" ng-value="account" name="pbonus" readonly>` (`ng-value` instead of `ng-model`)

Comment: Ok , I understand the problem.